# (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null) In example play project (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have Typesafe Activator (1.3.6) installed and I would like to run play-scala-intro project. Unfortunately, while building this example(!) code, I get following errors:

> Read from stdout: (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved
>   dependency: io.netty#netty;3.10.4.Final: several problems occurred
>   while resolving dependency: io.netty#netty;3.10.4.Final
>   {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}: Read
>   from stdout:  several problems occurred while resolving dependency:
>   org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;9 {}: Read from stdout:
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null Read
>   from stdout:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host
>   = null Read from stdout:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null Read from stdout:  Read from stdout:    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null Read
>   from stdout:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host
>   = null (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.netty#netty;3.10.4.Final: several problems occurred while resolving
>   dependency: io.netty#netty;3.10.4.Final {compile=[compile(*),
>   master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}:  several problems occurred
>   while resolving dependency: org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;9 {}:
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null Total
>   time: 17 s, completed 2015-09-09 21:22:28

What is wrong? What can be the reason for these IllegalArgument exceptions???

Comment: You seem to have problems with your environment, as SBT fails to resolve dependencies. Can you create an empty sbt project compile it, then add any dependency (e.g. `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4"`), compile it again. That will at least ensure that your sbt is set up correctly.

Comment: Empty SBT with your dependency compiles correctly. Everything works perfect. Have you got any other ideas?

Comment: Another ida in the absence of any other information is to try to add `resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"` directly to your sbt file. Otherwise, it may help to know what OS do you use and how sbt file looks like.

Comment: My OS is Windows 8.1. The same problem occures with several different dependencies. ScalaTest works fine, but XSBT gives me the same error. I have edited my post and added build.sbt file. I'm using the newest JDK 1.8.0, but the same problem exists when I change it for JDK 7. @Tim

Comment: I fact there is no need to post my sbt files. They are exactly the same like in play-scala-intro example in activator. Plus I added sonatype to resolvers - it didn't help. The main problem here seems to be all those protocol = http | host = null... but what can  be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, but in my repositories file (in .sbt folder) all the URLs had two times more "/" than they should. After removing excessive slashes everything works perfectly.